# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_v8js.dll'

Tags: php

**To solve error**

> Class 'V8Js' not found

Did following changes in my xampp

```
IN  \php\ folder:

v8.dll
icui18n.dll (php7)
icuuc.dll (php7)
those files added
And 
IN \php\ext\ folder:

php_v8js.dll
then made this change in php.ini file
; V8 Javascript Engine Module
extension=php_v8js.dll
```

then I restart my server then also i give **same error**

> "Class 'V8Js' not found"

```
Php =>7.2.11
System  Windows => NT DESKTOP-1067LL0 10.0 build 17134 (Windows 10) i586
Build Date =>   Oct 10 2018 02:03:59
Compiler    =>MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017)
Architecture    =>x86
```

Comment: Tried remove the ".dll" from php.ini ? where did you download php_v8js.dll ? try download from official site and be sure of get the appropriate for your installation : Thread safe/ No thread safe , x64 , x86 , etc...

Comment: Thread safe ,x86 from this side 
[link](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6359 )